# sql server #region

Tags: sql-server, region

Can I create regions in sql server editor (like `#region` and `#endregion` in C#) ?

Comment: If anyone is looking for the mysql equivalent, use `--#region Some text` and `--#endregion`

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Not really, Sorry! But...

Adding `begin` and `end`.. with a comment on the `begin` creates regions which would look like this...**bit of hack though!**

[image: screenshot of begin end region code]

Otherwise you can only expand and collapse you just can't dictate what should be expanded and collapsed. Not without a third-party tool such as [SSMS Tools Pack](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).

Comment: Ensure you have Outline Statement enabled under 
Text Editor > Transact-SQL>Intellisense>Enable Intellisense

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225998(v=sql.80).aspx. Although all Transact-SQL statements are valid within a BEGIN...END block, certain Transact-SQL statements should not be grouped together within the same batch (statement block). Could anyone tell me why they should not be grouped?

Comment: Useful hack, but don't forget to add `go` after the `end` statement if you want to create multiple regions/sections.

Comment: Fine! If you have comment block only. You have to add something with not comment within. for example: print

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in every case, unless I'm missing something.  It seems to break at least if you're using `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 26):

(I am developer of [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com) add-in for SSMS)

We have recently added support for this syntax into our SSMSBoost add-in.

```
--#region [Optional Name]
--#endregion
```

It has also an option to automatically "recognize" regions when opening scripts.

Comment: It is OK but doesn't work on the fly. I have to close and reopen file to collapse newly created regions.

Comment: There is a "reparse regions" option, available in SSMSBoost menu on the toolbar. So, no need to reopen the file.

Comment: Unfortunately this has a bug.  If the first code statements within the region are commented out the region ended at last commented out line of code

Comment: FYI: not open source

Answer (score 11):

BEGIN...END works, you just have to add a commented section.  The easiest way to do this is to add a section name!  Another route is to add a comment block.  See below:

```
BEGIN  -- Section Name
/* 
Comment block some stuff  --end comment should be on next line
*/

 --Very long query
SELECT * FROM FOO
SELECT * FROM BAR
END
```

Answer (score 8):

It is just a matter of using text indentation in the query editor.

**Expanded View:**

[image: Expanded]

**Collapsed View:**

[image: Collapsed]

Answer (score 7):

Not out of the box in Sql Server Management Studio, but it is a [feature](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=10) of the very good [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/)

Comment: Caveat: it costs €30 with 60 day demo.

Comment: When this was originally posted the extension was free

Comment: regions in SSMS Tools Pack are slightly different of those in Visual Studio. They seem to begin only at the lines following the region directive, and they are not always available and working as expected, especially in long scripts. I like SSMS TP but I don't find this specific feature reliable.

Answer (score 4):

No, #region does not exist in the T-SQL language.

You can get code-folding using begin-end blocks:

```
-- my region
begin
    -- code goes here
end
```

I'm not sure I'd recommend using them for this unless the code cannot be acceptably refactored by other means though!

Answer (score 4):

I've used a technique similar to McVitie's, and only in stored procedures or scripts that are pretty long.  I will break down certain functional portions like this:

```
BEGIN /** delete queries **/

DELETE FROM blah_blah

END /** delete queries **/

BEGIN /** update queries **/

UPDATE sometable SET something = 1

END /** update queries **/
```

This method shows up fairly nice in management studio and is really helpful in reviewing code.  The collapsed piece looks sort of like:

```
BEGIN /** delete queries **/ ... /** delete queries **/
```

I actually prefer it this way because I know that my `BEGIN` matches with the `END` this way.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

if your purpose is analyse your query, Notepad+ has useful automatic wrapper for Sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a plugin to SSMS you can do it like this and get the collapsible and expandable code blocks

```
BEGIN --#region [DisplayDate]
    
    SELECT GETDATE() CurrentDate

END   --#endregion
```

[image: Using regions in SQL code sections]

[image: Using regions in SQL code sections - collapsed section]

You don't have to add ***#region*** and ***#endregion*** and can just specify the description in it's place as others have suggested previously.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22633580/1165173

Answer (score -1):

begin
--do something
end
GO

begin
--do something else
end
GO

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference with the existing answers?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use formatting to improve the representatsion of your code-only answer. Ideally add a prose explanation of how this works and why it helps. Make sure to point out the addditional insight which your answer contributes beyond existing answers. Because currently your answer does, and will even  more so with proper formatting, give the impression of being a worse formatted, unexplained, reiteration of existing answers. Try for [answer] and consider taking the [tour].