# How to organize parts of T-SQL scripts in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm having a problem with organizing SQL scripts that contain more than 10k lines of code.

Let's say there's a declaration of 10 variables:

```
-- declaration
DECLARE @SaleId1 int
DECLARE @SaleId2 int
DECLARE @SaleId3 int
DECLARE @SaleId4 int
DECLARE @SaleId5 int
DECLARE @SaleId6 int
DECLARE @SaleId7 int
DECLARE @SaleId8 int
DECLARE @SaleId9 int
DECLARE @SaleId10 int
```

Is there any way to format this code so there would appear minus symbol allowing me to hide all the content and leave just comment?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server #region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386099/sql-server-region)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code regions are not natively supported in SQL Server Management Studio.
In order to organize your code, you have a few options:

- Refactor to introduce stored procedure and user defined functions
- Use the “code region hack” defined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386099/sql-server-region) post
- Install the [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which provides advanced format features

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS , goto **Tools** > **Options** .

In dialog box find node **Transact-SQL** > **Intellisense**

Check **Outline Statements** option.

Reopen the Sql Script.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use:

```
-- declaration
DECLARE @SaleId1 int
,@SaleId2 int
,@SaleId3 int
,@SaleId4 int
,@SaleId5 int
,@SaleId6 int
,@SaleId7 int
,@SaleId8 int
,@SaleId9 int
,@SaleId10 int
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have added regions support into my add-in: www.ssmsboost.com (starting from v 2.12)
Syntax:

```
--#region [OptionalName]

--#endregion
```