# SQL: Can't Create SP Inside If Block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, scripting

I am attempting to run some SQL queries if a table doesn't already exist, specifically:

1. Create the table.
2. Add some data.
3. Create a stored procedure to access the data.

Step 1 and 2 work fine, but when I try to do the third part, I get an error. Here is my code (don't need to read thoroughly - here for reference, skip to problem area below):

```
USE [MyDB]
GO


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='fooTable' and xtype='U')
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE fooTable
        (
            ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
            SomeNumber INT NOT NULL, 
            SomeOtherTable_ID INT NOT NULL, 
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            FOREIGN KEY (SomeOtherTable_ID) REFERENCES SomeOtherTable(SomeOtherTable_ID)
        );

        INSERT INTO fooTable (SomeNumber, SomeOtherTable_ID)
        VALUES (5, 1), (10, 1), (25, 1), (50, 1), (100, 1), (500, 1)

        CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedureName
        AS
        SELECT SomeNumber from [fooTable]
    END
```

The relevant trouble line is the third one here, it works fine OUTSIDE of the if statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedureName
AS
SELECT SomeNumber from [fooTable]
```

but if I try to run it in the if block, `SELECT` gets underlined in red with the following:

> Incorrect syntax near SELECT. Expecting EXTERNAL.

How do I run the stored procedure inside the if block? If it's relevant, this is in SQL Server using T-SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stored procedures, triggers, functions, and several other object types need to be in their own batch. This can be achieved within an `IF` block by wrapping the `CREATE` statement in an `EXEC(N'....')`:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.footTable') IS NULL)
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE dbo.[fooTable]
   (
      ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
           CONSTRAINT [PK_fooTable] PRIMARY KEY,
      SomeNumber INT NOT NULL, 
      SomeOtherTable_ID INT NOT NULL
           CONSTRAINT [FK_fooTable_SomeOtherTable] FOREIGN KEY
           REFERENCES dbo.SomeOtherTable(SomeOtherTable_ID)
   );

   INSERT INTO dbo.fooTable (SomeNumber, SomeOtherTable_ID)
   VALUES (5, 1), (10, 1), (25, 1), (50, 1), (100, 1), (500, 1);

   EXEC(N'
        CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProcedureName
        AS
        SELECT SomeNumber FROM [fooTable];
   ');
END;
```

Notes:

- Be sure to include the capital-`N` prefix on string literals containing dynamic SQL (as a best practice -- yes, not having it often works, but having it always works).
- Don't use deprecated compatibility views such as `sysobjects`. Starting with the release of SQL Server 2005, the proper system catalog views are in the `sys` schema. In this case, it would be `sys.objects`.
- You should schema-qualify the objects: `dbo.fooTable` instead of just `fooTable`
- You should name your constraints: PK, FKs, etc.

Comment: Thanks! //comment length

Comment: @VSO Yer welcome. I made some updates to improve the code. Please take a look.

Comment: I appreciate it - I was actually going to ask for an explanation on N, but google answered it quickly.  I was also wondering about the second point since Vince used sys.objects, but I have seen it recommended as sysobjects.

Comment: @VSO Actually, Vince used `sys.procedures` which is a subset of `sys.objects` but with some additional columns. Still, using `sys___` without any period in there has been a bad idea starting with SQL Server 2005, no matter how many examples of it are out there, and no matter how recent any of them are.

Comment: Was just pointing out that you hit the nail on the head with the notes you added, since you corrected me on the bad practiced I saw elsewhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE PROCEDURE needs to be in its own block. Move it out and do something like:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.procedures  WHERE NAME = 'myProcedureName' AND type = 'P')
     DROP PROCEDURE myProcedureName
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedureName
AS
SELECT SomeNumber from [fooTable]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there no way to put it inside the block?

Comment: Not in the same block. "CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE TRIGGER, and CREATE VIEW statements cannot be combined with other statements in a batch". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019512/why-shouldnt-transact-sql-statements-be-grouped-together-within-the-same-batch

Comment: P = SQL Stored Procedure. sys.procedures contains a row for each object that is a procedure of some kind, with sys.objects.type = P, X, RF, and PC. The description can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I like the following idiom:

```
if object_id('dbo.yourProc') is not null --object exists
   set noexec on;
go
create procedure dbo.yourProc as
begin
   select 'not implemented' as [message]
end
go
set noexec off;
go
alter procedure dbo.yourProc as
begin
   «actual definition here»
end
go
```

What I like about this is that preserves any permissions that already exist on the procedure and is idempotent.