# T-SQL How to Collapse column lists into nodes

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is 4000 lines long. It updates or inserts about 24 tables. Most of it is column lists and transformations. The processing logic is only about 60 lines. I can use begin end statements to collapse sections of the code into nodes. Is there a way to expand all nodes and collapse all nodes with one click?

Comment: _recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial_ are off-topic here.

Comment: SSMS has this functionality, no?

Comment: 4,000 lines sounds like an awful lot of columns for what you are describing.  You could always just comment out the columns, in SSMS comments are collapsible as a single block. Or an entire query is collapsible already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386099/sql-server-region

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386099/sql-server-region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386099/sql-server-region)